# Adding user input to an array

Tags: python, arrays, numpy

I've just started learning python.
I'm doing this for a school project.

I cannot use a list for storing the passengers ages, I need to do a 2d array and I'm just lost.

How do I add the values of "age" into an array?
I've gott it working with a list, but that won't be enough.
I've tried messing around with numpy but I must be doing something wrong, please help me.
I want the array to be 4x8 to represent the seats in the bus.

So, this is what I've got so far. It's far from finished but I got stuck on this.

This is the error I get:
AttributeError: 'numpy.ndarray' object has no attribute 'np'

```
import numpy as np
import random as rd
passenger_ages=np.zeros([4,8],dtype=int)




class Bus:
    def run():
        print('==============================')
        print('Welcome to the bus simulator')
        print('==============================')
        print('What do you want to do?')
        print('1. Add passenger.')
        print('2. Print all passengers.')
        print('3. See other age options')
        choice=int(input('Make your choice: '))
        match choice:
            case 1:
                Bus.add_passenger()
            case 2:
                Bus.print_all()
            case 3:
                Bus.age_numbers()
    
    def print_all():
        print(passenger_ages)

    def age_numbers():
        print('What do you want to see?')
        print('1. Combined age.')
        print('2. Average age.')
        print('3. Oldest on the bus.')
        print('Youngest on the bus.')
    

           
    def add_passenger():
        pass_no=0
        try:
            age=int(input('Passengers age: '))
            passenger_ages.np.append(age)
            pass_no+=1
            print(f'You added a passenger with the age: {age}')
            again=input('Do you want to add more passengers?(J/N)')
            if again=='j' or again=='J':
                Bus.add_passenger()
            elif pass_no>32:
                print('Buss is full.')
                Bus.run()
            else:
                Bus.run()
        except ValueError:
            print('Only numbers.')
    
            
Bus.run()
```

Comment: Do you know the code to set a value in a np array at column x and row y? Do you know the mathematical formula that gives you the row and column of a seat assuming they are numbered 1 to 32?

Comment: Thanks for responding. No, I can't say that I do. right now my brain is completely fried. Been up 2 nights in a row with this and it's due in a couple of days. Maybe I just need some sleep and take another crack at it tomorrow.

Answer (score 0):

So when you work with numpy arrays they have indexes, like lists. But since they're multi-dimensional you have to call more than one axis.

If you replace line `passenger_ages.np.append(age)` with `passenger_ages[pass_no][x] = age` then you can get this working. In this case `pass_no` will increment each time you add a passenger since you've implemented that functionality. You will also need to add a functionality to increment x as well.

You need two indexes due to the fact it's a 2d array. Think of them like X, y coordinates on a chart.

Here's some code to get you pointed in the right direction (I'm not going to finish your school work for you lol). In order to finish this properly you'll need to change the incrementing functions to properly index on each line. *Hint: I'd use if/else statements to check and see when it's time to increment pass_no since it has to stay the same for several passengers while just x increments each time, however there are about twenty ways to do this.*

See also: [numpy.asarray](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.asarray.html) and [numpy.reshape](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.reshape.html) for another solution.

```
import numpy as np
import random as rd

passenger_ages = np.zeros([4, 8], dtype=int)
pass_no = 0
x = 0

class Bus:

    def run():
        print('==============================')
        print('Welcome to the bus simulator')
        print('==============================')
        print('What do you want to do?')
        print('1. Add passenger.')
        print('2. Print all passengers.')
        print('3. See other age options')
        choice = int(input('Make your choice: '))
        match choice:
            case 1:
                Bus.add_passenger()
            case 2:
                Bus.print_all()
            case 3:
                Bus.age_numbers()

    def print_all():
        print(passenger_ages)

    def age_numbers():
        print('What do you want to see?')
        print('1. Combined age.')
        print('2. Average age.')
        print('3. Oldest on the bus.')
        print('Youngest on the bus.')

    def add_passenger():
        global pass_no
        global x

        try:
            age = int(input('Passengers age: '))
            passenger_ages[pass_no][x] = age
            # passenger_ages.np.append(age)
            pass_no += 1
            x += 1
            print(f'You added a passenger with the age: {age}')
            again = input('Do you want to add more passengers?(J/N)')
            if again == 'j' or again == 'J':
                Bus.add_passenger()
            elif pass_no > 32:
                print('Buss is full.')
                Bus.run()
            else:
                Bus.run()
        except ValueError:
            print('Only numbers.')


Bus.run()
```

Comment: There's an error here: you are incrementing both `pass_no` and `x` when adding a new passenger. So the array is being indexed in the way [0][0], [1][1], [2][2], ... , [32][32] --- however your array is only of size (4, 8).

Comment: One possible solution would be to not have any x at all, and to simply do `passenger_ages[pass_no // 8][pass_no % 8] = age`.

Comment: Thank you both. I was almost about to bive up and go back to being a bricklayer, lol. "passenger_ages[pass_no // 8][pass_no % 8] = age" does exactly what I want, I'm not quite sure how though, haha.

Comment: @Mercury I didn't want to do all his work for him haha but yeah that's a very elegant solution to the issue.

Comment: Thanks for the help, both were really helpful, I almost had an if/else solution with the x value when that other line came. I figured out how it worked and it is indeed very elegant. I would never have thought of that myself but next time I will so I learned a lot. Cheers